# Does VSEXPRESS.EXE or MSBUILD.EXE end up compiling with CL.EXE and link with LINK.EXE

Tags: compilation, linker, filesize

Why when I compile `work.c` with `VCExpress test.sln /build "Release" /project "test"` or `msbuild` output file is `8 kb` and when I create it with `CL.exe /Tp w.c user32.lib` final output is `37 kb`

Don't they all (vsexpress, msbuild, nmake) at the end compile with `CL.EXE` and link with `LINK.EXE`? (If you could simply answer this It'll make it very easy for me because then I know that the answer lies down somewhere in `cl.exe` or `link.exe` options and switches)

what did vsexpress do in this process?
did it compile it with a kind of `cl.exe` command that caused the smaller size?
did it link it differently?

**btw**: the code is nothing special a simple window with a button copied from msdn but If you must here it is: http://textuploader.com/o4qt

*I hope that all of them compile with `CL.EXE` and link with `LINK.EXE` If you say not so you'll make me very sad (fingers crossed)*

Comment: Perhaps the difference in file size may be the result of various default flags used by `msbuild` and friends. A better comparison would be to copy the flags the project will use, and pass those _explicitly_ to `cl`

Comment: If you use msbuild to build a solution you'll get the CL.exe and LINK.exe calls somewhere in the console output. Compare the switches applied to your manual calls. My guess is that you'll see some linker optimization automatically applied by msbuild.